# How to best communicate model improvements to non-technical stakeholders?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model-evaluation, reporting

Working on a project to improve a model, and I want to be able to communicate to non-technical people how much the model has improved with recent work. Here are example numbers showing the improvement:

```
    R^2: 
    before: 0.2485, after: 0.3215
    percent_change: +29%

    Mean Absolute Error: 

    before: 115,968 after: 110,836
    percent_change: -4.5%

    3. Mean Squared Error 

    before: 23654110322 after: 23440242264
    percent_change: -12%
```

How do you recommend communicating improvements like this? Could you make a list of example statements you might use? Here's some examples of what I think would go over really well, but I don't want to be inaccurate or unethical in any way of course.

"We reduced error by about 5%"

"Improved predictive power by 29%" (based off R^2, I suspect this is wrong)

Comment: If this is for a business, give the expected business result. For example: at a factory where this model change *should* result in 4.5 percent less electrical power used per month, business users can easily convert that into a 4.5 percent reduction in electrical power *expense*. That is to say, the business result of the change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this is good advice. Unfortunately, the business outcome is tough to quantify, but this helped.